# A question about .htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I'm redeveloping a site for a client.

Their current site is written in .asp. I've rebuilt in WordPress as they need a CMS.

We're repointing the DNS to our hosting environment.

My question is - I need to set up an .htaccess file (I think this is the best way) to redirect all the old URLs to their new equivalent. Some of the URL structures have changed so it's not just a case of changing .asp > .php. Soo... where should I upload the .htaccess file - does this need to go in the root directory OR does it need to go in my wp-theme folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the .htaccess to the root of the website however be cautious as WordPress will have added it's own if you have changed the link slug structure within the WordPress admin.

In the htaccess file you should use 301 re-direction's like so:

```
redirect 301 /oldpage.asp http://www.thesite.com/newpage/
```

If it is a big site then you will not want to re-direct all pages although it could be worth while. I normally just do a Google site: search and re-direct the most important pages and any with first or second page listings.

Comment: Hiya - thanks for the reply. There are only 6 pages on the old site so it's quite manageable. I've checked and wp has created an .htacess file - can i just add my redirects after the wp code?

Comment: Yeah that should be fine, but obviously make sure you test it thoroughly!